no need for change of an ice cream store
There are n + m people waiting in line at an ice cream store. Among them, n people have
only 1-dollar bills, and the remaining m people have only 2-dollar bills. Each ice cream
costs 1 dollar. Initially, the ice cream store has p 1-dollar bills. If each customer buys only
1 ice cream, what is the probability that none of them will have to wait for change?
This means we need to assure that p+ # of 1-dollar people >= # of 2-dollar people all the time. I know that for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem we have a formula. But the thing is that we have a p added in the initial.

Just curious: did you come up with this puzzle yourself?

@FirstNameLastName No it was from a friend.

Personally I do not see this as a mathematics problem, as opposed to a mathematical puzzle. For one thing the first, and for question at hand, sufficient paragraph, does not mention any mathematical terminology, apart from the word probability, which, I hope, is not banned here. On the contrary, I think this puzzle succeeds in perfectly turning a problem into a puzzle. People waiting in line at an ice cream store holding dollar bills is a beautiful representation IMO.

Answer:

$$1-\frac{\binom{m+n}{n+p+1}}{\binom{m+n}{n}}=1-\frac{m(m-1)\cdots(m-p)}{(n+p+1)(n+p)\cdots(n+1)}.$$

Explanation:

 The proof is essentially the same as the one given in the Wikipedia article here. We map every sequence of purchases at the store with a path on the grid $\mathbb Z^2$, where a step to the right corresponds to a person with \$1 bill making a purchase, and one step upward corresponds to a person with \$2 bill making a purchase. In the original ballot problem (i.e., $p=0$), the paths start at $(0,0)$ and end at $(n,m)$. But since the store already has $p$ \$1 bills, our paths start at $(p,0)$ and end at $(n+p,m)$. The total number of such paths, which is the total number of sequences of purchases, is simply $$\binom{n+m}{n}.$$ Call a path good if no customer has to wait, and bad otherwise. It is easy to see that a good path always lies strictly below the line $y=x+1$ and a bad path doesn't. Now, if a path is bad, we can take the initial part of it up to the point where it first touches the $y=x+1$ line and reflect it about that line. This gives us a path from $(-1,p+1)$ to $(n+p,m)$, which still goes up or right in each step. It is easy to convince oneself that any bad path corresponds to a unique path from $(-1,p+1)$ to $(n+p,m)$. Therefore, the number of bad paths is $$\binom{(n+p+1)+(m-p-1)}{n+p+1} = \binom{n+m}{n+p+1}.$$ The number of good paths is simply the the difference of these two numbers, and the probability of no waiting customer is the ratio of number of good paths and the total number of paths.

Sanity checks:



 When $p=0$, we have to get back the answer for the ballot problem, and indeed we do. Note that the usual version of ballot problem asks for one of the candidates to always be strictly ahead (i.e., no ties allowed at any point), which gives $\frac{n-m}{n+m}$ as the answer. However, the variant that's relevant here is when ties are allowed, so the answer in this case is $\frac{n+1-m}{n+1}$, which does check out.




 When $m\le p$, there is no way the store can run out of change, so there is never any waiting customer. Therefore, the answer should be $1$. Indeed, when $m\le p$, we have $\binom{n+m}{n+p+1} = 0$ by definition (one of the factors in the numerator on the RHS of the answer is $(m-m)$), so that checks out too.




 We also want the probability to be nonnegative. Indeed, we can write the answer as$$1-\frac{n}{n+p+1}\cdot \frac{m}{n+p}\cdot \frac{m-1}{n+p-1} \cdots \frac{m-p}{n}.$$ When $m\le n+p$, each of the ratios in the second term is $\le1$, so their product is also $\le1$, and hence, the answer is nonnegative.




I can confirm that this nice formula gives same outcomes as a recursive formula I used.

fwiw : P(n,m,p)=(n/(n+m))*P(n-1,m,p+1)+(m/(n+m))*P(n,m-1,p-1) is the recursive formula I used (omitting here the required starter values)


 We simply subtract p from m  i.e.  [n - (m - p)]/[n + (m-p)]

Motivation:

  We could simply run p people from group m through the queue first, then we end up with the above equation.


That doesn’t answer the question really, which is what is the probability nobody has to wait for change if the customers arrive in a random order. If you partly specify their order to suit you, you no longer have the conditions being asked about.
